# Executing a bash script in R

Tags: r, bash

I have a bash script that runs some loops and exits an CSV file that i use it in my R Function that i write in Rstudio. I want to trigger this bash script with in my R Function in Rstudio.

Example bash script generating out.csv :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello,People" >> out.csv
```

How i am using it in my R script:

```
outinfo = read.csv(file = "out.csv" , header = TRUE )
```

Answer (score 1):

`system(command)` is what you are looking for.

> system invokes the OS command specified by command.